# group SQL 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if this is a proper title for my question, but I am not an advanced SQL user, I know only the basics :)

```
create table movie (id int(4), title varchar(255));

create table genre (id int(4), mid int(4), genre varchar(200));

insert into movie values
(1, 'Iron man'),
(2, 'Titanic');

insert into genre values
(1,1,'Sci-Fi'),
(2,1,'Action'),
(3,2,'Drama');
```

Here I have 2 tables, one for movies and one for genres.

I want to create a SQL that will look like this.

```
ID   |   Title   |  Genre

1    |  Iron Man |  Action, Sci-Fi
```

In the table genres `mid` is the ID of the movie from `movie table`..

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: YOu need to tell us what database you are using as teh solution is very database dependant.

Comment: I dont know, the one for web, PHP, i don't know what kind of sql is that, probably MySql ... :X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all Movies with `Genre` details :

```
SELECT 
    m.id AS ID,
    m.title AS Title,
    group_concat(g.genre) AS Genre
FROM 
    movie m
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre g ON (g.mid = m.id)
GROUP BY m.id
```

[**See on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9f56/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
select movie.id, title, group_concat(genre) from movie 
left join genre on mid=movie.id
where movie.id=1
group by movie.id
```